# Async elements that act as a form without a submit button

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, asynchronous

Okay, so this may seem like a lot to ask.  I have been pounding my head against the desk trying to figure this out.  Take the below example:

```
<ul>
   <li>Number: <span id="Number">123</span></li>
</ul>
```

I am wanting to create basically an asyncronous link between the span with the id of "Number", and the database.  Is it possible to give the user the ability to click the element, then the input can be changed, and then the updated value be sent to the database on either Enter/Return or unfocus?  This is just a small personal project, I am wanting to add a little bit of uniqueness to this.  So any help would be fantastic!

**UPDATE

So now I have it almost where it needs to be.  However the `apiCall()` function will not call using the interpolation method of showing data.  Any ideas on how to get around this?  Below is the code and the error:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Expense</th>
                <th scope="col">Amount</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <ng-container *ngFor="let exp of expenses">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><input type="text" class="formless" name="{{exp.expense}}" placeholder="{{exp.expense}}" (focusout)="apiCall({{exp.id}}, {{exp.expense}})"></th>
                    <td><input type="text" class="formless" placeholder="{{exp.price}}"></td>
                  </tr>
              </ng-container>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Error:

```
error NG5002: Parser Error: Unexpected
token {, expected identifier, keyword, or
string at column 10 in [apiCall({{exp.id}},
{{exp.expense}})] in
<path>\budget-app\src\app\home\home.component.html@29:137
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try with `<input/>` instead of span, so that it is always editable. For saving on update, you could bring in some function on `(focusout)` in html.

`<input [(ngModel)]="variableForStoringData" (focusout)="saveApiCall()" />`

Comment: I am getting an error, I know its basic js as far as the error is but the issue is it will not send it with the variables unless I use a string.  Which it just sends the interpolation items rather than the data they represent.  I am appending my post now to show.

Comment: I see what I did wrong.  In the function call I do not need to use interpolation, just use the variable created by the interpolation.  So when I changed it to `apiCall(exp.id, exp.expense)` the error was corrected.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can add in an input box inside the span and remove the border. Then assign the blur event listener to that input box and run your code to update the db.

The snippet below demonstrates this by writing the value to the console  when leaving the input box. You can replace that and add in your code to write to the database.

```js
document.querySelector(`#Number`).addEventListener(`blur`, (event) => {
  const val = event.target.value;
  console.log(val);
  //TODO: your code to transmit data
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

input {
  border: none;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Number:
    <span>
    <input id="Number" type="number" value="123">
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Steve, you should use `(blur)` in the .html (it's the "Angular style") not create a listener in a "javaScript style",

Comment: Gotcha. The OP didn't specify Angular in the description. It was edited 16 hours after I posted my answer.